# Stop bash echoing command text

Tags: bash, echo

I have been given a personal profile on a linux project server running bash 3.2.15. Every time I run a command it echoes the text of the command to screen. This isn't a serious issue, but it bugs the crap out of me. I can't find any specific command in .profile or .bashrc that sets this up, and everything I find through google is how to enable it. Not how to disable it. Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: shell scripts don't generally echo the individual commands, and since you haven't provided any code to look at, we can't help you.

Comment: Is this in the context of a script, or when executing commands interactively?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like debugging has been enabled (using `set -x`). You can disable it using `set +x`.